# Where can I find line buffering code?

Tags: math, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, polynomial-math

I can't find any code for doing this. The only places I can find it is in GIS APIs. Preferably in java, but I can port other languages too. I'd even settle for a overview of all the formulas required.

Comment: I happen to know what line buffering means, but you may want to explain it. Also, please specify the desire input/output formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

1. The method `Geometry.buffer(distance)`
   in Java Topology Suite (JTS) library http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm
2. The GEOS
   http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/
   port of JTS library to C++.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little puzzled by your question, so this may not be the (type of) answer you are looking for.

Look for line buffering code in the source files of any of the open-source GIS out there.  there are several.

As for algorithms, I Googled for *gis buffering* and got several useful hits on the first page.